# How to generate swift files for protobuf

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers

I have .proto files from my employee. Now I need to connect to service with this proto instructions. As I understood I need to generate some files for my swift project for boxing/unboxing my messages. 
But I can't understand how to do this. I've found many instructions how to install protobuf.

Can anyone explain step by step what I need to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per `ProtocolBuffers-Swift`'s install instructions:

> ...
>
> 5. `git clone git@github.com:alexeyxo/protobuf-swift.git`
> 6. `./scripts/build.sh`
> 7. Add `./src/ProtocolBuffers/ProtocolBuffers.xcodeproj` in your project.

Their [page on CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/pods/ProtocolBuffers-Swift) includes some basic uses, as well:

```
message Person {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
    optional string email = 3;
}

let personBuilder = Person.builder()
personBuilder.id = 123
personBuilder.name = "Bob"
personBuilder.email = "bob@example.com"
let person = personBuilder.build()
println("\(person)")

person.data() //return NSData

...

var person = Person.parseFromData(bytes) // from NSData
```